# Controlling mapview gesture delegate in swift

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, swift, uigesturerecognizer

I am using SWRevealViewController (a slide view controller) in my app. But my centerview is a mapview. So obviously my sliding from left to right wont reveal the left hidden view controller , actually the mapview will just pan.

So I am using the following code to disable the panning of `mapView` in the left most side of the `mapView` with the following code

```
NSArray *gestureRecognizers = [mapView gestureRecognizers];
for (UIGestureRecognizer *recognizer in gestureRecognizers) {
    if ([recognizer isKindOfClass:[UITapGestureRecognizer class]]) {
        //[v removeGestureRecognizer:recognizer];
    }

    if ([recognizer isKindOfClass:[UIPanGestureRecognizer class]]) {
        //[v removeGestureRecognizer:recognizer];
        recognizer.delegate=self;
    }
}
```

and handing the delegate as follows

```
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizerShouldBegin:(UIGestureRecognizer *)recognizer
{

CGPoint loc =[recognizer locationInView:self.mapView];

if (loc.x>50) {
    return YES;
}
return NO;
}
```

This is working fine in objective c

But now I am using the swift its not working
because 
in objective c  `NSArray *gestureRecognizers = [mapView gestureRecognizers];` the array have some elements but in case of swift

```
if let recognizers = mapView.gestureRecognizers {
        for recognizer in recognizers {
            println("founr gest")
            mapView.removeGestureRecognizer(recognizer as UIGestureRecognizer)
        }
    }
```

the gesture array is nil.

am I doing it wrong in swift?

OR
Long story short

is it possible to get the gesturerecognizer for mapview in swift

Comment: Can you show your code about adding the gestureRecognizer in Swift?

Comment: I have one mapView in IB which already have pan gesture attached to it. In objective c also i am iterating through all gesture in mapview and taking pangesture. i am not adding the geture. i am only assigning the delegate to self to handle "gestureRecognizerShouldBegin"

Comment: Have you find a solution ? I want to remove the rotation gesture in a GMSMapView.